# Trying to understand underlying code for bind method

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at a code snippet for a [bind implementation](https://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-apply-call-and-bind-methods-are-essential-for-javascript-professionals/) and am struggling to understand how this works:

```
// Credit to Douglas Crockford for this bind method
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
    Function.prototype.bind = function (oThis) {
        if (typeof this !== "function") {
            // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5 internal IsCallable function
            throw new TypeError ("Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable");
        }

        var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call (arguments, 1),
                fToBind = this,
                fNOP = function () {
                },
                fBound = function () {
                    return fToBind.apply (this instanceof fNOP && oThis
                            ? this
                            : oThis,
                            aArgs.concat (Array.prototype.slice.call (arguments)));
                };

        fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
        fBound.prototype = new fNOP ();

        return fBound;
    };
}
```

In order, I have the following questions:

1. How do I think about the `this` in: `if (typeof this !== "function")`? My understanding is that in general `this` refers to the object that owns/contains the function being called. In this case, is that object: A). Function.prototype? or B). the object that contains the function on which bind is applied (i.e., if we have `someFunc.bind(someObj)` then does the `this` above refer to the object that holds `someFunc`? If so, what if that object contains many other methods besides `someFunc`? And if that's the case, how do we deal with the possibility that the `this` object holds a lot of extraneous functions aside from our function of interest, `someFunc`?)
2. `var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call (arguments, 1)` . . . why is the `1` passed as a parameter to the call method?
3. In `fToBind = this` I have the same question as in #1 above. What *exactly* does `this` refer to?
4. What's the purpose of `(this instanceof fNOP && oThis)`? My (certainly incorrect) reading of this is that the 'truthy' case would be when `this` is an instance of an object that contains an empty function AND oThis is not NULL? And if this is the case, why does that lead to `this`, and if not the case, why to the 'falsey' case of `oThis`?
5. What's going on with the concatenation in: `aArgs.concat (Array.prototype.slice.call (arguments))`? Would not `arguments` here refer to the arguments to fBound? If so, why are we concatenating these with the arguments to the `bind` method (which is what I assume `aArgs` represents)?
6. What purpose does `fNOP.prototype = this.prototype; fBound.prototype = new fNOP ()` serve?
   After all, in the next line, the function returns `fBound`. Does returning `fBound` mean we're really returning `fBound.prototype` (i.e., a new instance of `fNOP()` which is `this.prototype`)? If so, wouldn't that ignore/"overwrite" the:

   ```
   fBound = function() {
            return fToBind.apply (this instanceof fNOP && oThis
                               ? this
                               : oThis, 
                               aArgs.concat
            (Array.prototype.slice.call (arguments)));
     }
   ```

   But if not, what purpose does the `fBound.prototype = new fNOP ()` assignment serve?